# Filtering a dictionary to access and graph certain values based on a specific datetime range in python

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime, indexing, filter

Hello I'm trying to filter and narrow down some values that I'm going to be using in a dictionary and it's kicking back the following error....

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 666104 but corresponding boolean dimension is 664213

and the last line in the code is whats giving me the problem.  Sorry I don't work too often with dictionaries but I'm pretty sure that the syntax is correct:

```
### This loop will go through datetimes in the excel file and grab the ### satellite
### and satellite that we will pull data from

for (a, b) in zip(Date_List, Sat_List):
    ###  Print to see which date we are currently using
    print(a)
    
    
    #### get all of the stuff from these cluster satellites and turn it     ####into a dicrtionary
    #### a feeds the date, b feeds the satellite integer
    #### 12 is a time interval on each side of the used date

    Data_Dict = tw.fetch_cluster_data(a, b, 12)
    
    ####  Set up start and stop times so that we can narrow our data ####down early

    start_Time = a - timedelta(hours = 12)
    end_Time   = a + timedelta(hours = 12)
    
    
    #### Set up a filter to narrow down the stuff from the massive ####dictionary 
    #### That we just made

    filter = (Data_Dict['cis_time']>=start_Time) & (Data_Dict['cis_time']<=end_Time)
    
    #### Pulls the datetime objects in the correct range atm
    CIS_time = Data_Dict['cis_time'][filter]
    
    #### This line fucks up and kicks back the error  
    Bx = Data_Dict['b'][filter, 0]
'''
```

Comment: I guess your index doesn't have proper range. It should be consecutive incremental in nature. like 1,2,3,4 not 1,3,4

Comment: Gotchya, ty very much!!